# Getting Out of memory error in Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, android-kenburnsview

I have added the [cresentroContainer](https://github.com/developer-shivam/Crescento) for rounded image bottom and [KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView) library to animate the image.  After that I am getting out of memory error and also android studio become very slow.

Comment: are you using bitmaps for images?

Comment: no.. I am assigning image using xml. using android:src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have large images (perhaps large w.r.t your current device whihch has lower heap size in which you are testing) in your drawable, which you are assigning to your views in XML. 
You can downscale your images and then assign to views programticaly, for downscaling simply load your images via Picasso or Glid. Also You can do android:largeHeap = "true" in your manifest under application tag which is obviously not recommended by many of programmers.

Comment: if I use any universal image loader, then my app size will also increases..  I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

Since that library make use of images just update your manifest as,

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Mall"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo_for_up"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```